# "You don't have [PATH ]in your PATH, gem executables will not run." while using "gem install --user-install bundler"

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I was trying to install jekyll in my Mac and got the warning as following:

> WARNING:  You don't have /Users/Carrot/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin in
>   your PATH, gem executables will not run.

I checked through gem list and it shows it is installed; and I can find the jekyll through the path "/Users/Carrot/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin". I read a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886835/just-installed-sass-on-osx-what-is-this-warning-you-dont-have-users-orio) which seems like my situation. I would like to know if it's a must to go through `sudo`? I now prefer to uninstall everything (since it also installed sass and bunch of things at the same time) and go through homebrew. How can I do the uninstallation?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 47):

For those who have problems with @lamech-desai answer, (actually, when they do *Desai's* commands, it apparently works temporarily for them).
So you can easily do these:

open `~/.bashrc` if you would like to use bash or `~/.zshrc` if your are using zsh *or etc...*

```
$ nano .bashrc    ## bash users
$ nano .zshrc     ## zsh users
```

then copy and past these two lines of code at the end of the .*rc file:

```
export GEM_HOME="$(ruby -e 'puts Gem.user_dir')"
export PATH="$PATH:$GEM_HOME/bin"
```

then simply press `ctrl+s` and `ctrl+x`. This will save the changes to `.bashrc` but you won't see them immediately - directly on your next shell login with your current user. One way to see the changes immediately is to type `source .bashrc` - and voila, your `.bashrc` will be reloaded. You can also check this with `echo $PATH`.

> Thanks to @lamech-desai for great answer

Comment: Do not forget to reload your `.bashrc` settings after doing this or else you won't see this change immediately. One way to do this is to `su root`, then `su <your user>` again, and you will then see ruby in your path. You also check this with `echo $PATH`.

Comment: You should avoid using `sudo` on your .*rc file since it's specific to each user, and using root to modify it could cause permission issues

Answer (score 15):

If you are using arch linux just use the commands below in your terminal

```
[user~]$ export GEM_HOME="$(ruby -e 'puts Gem.user_dir')"
[user~]$ export PATH="$PATH:$GEM_HOME/bin"
[user~]$ gem list
[user~]$ gem update
```

Comment: Do you have to run this every time you startup the computer?

Comment: Where does the export command save these variables to permanently? I thought closing the shell clears them

Comment: Use qafoori's solution below if you are facing issues related to temporary set up since this solution depends on the system you are using

Answer (score 12):

If you are on a Mac like me, you need to add the `PATH` to the `PATH` environmental variable. You can do it with `export` command:

```
export PATH="/Users/Carrot/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin:$PATH"
```

If you wanna know more about this process, here is a blog post about this: [Adding a Path to the Linux PATH Variable](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/path-variable#:%7E:text=The%20PATH%20variable%20is%20an%20environment%20variable%20that,%2Fbin%2Fecho%20so%20long%20as%20%2Fbin%20is%20in%20PATH%3A)

Comment: There should be no need as such to `export` this variable a second time; your shell will already have done that for you, in all but the utmost esoteric scenarios.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add the directory to your PATH environment variable

https://askubuntu.com/questions/406643/warning-you-dont-have-a-directory-in-your-path-gem-executables-will-not-run

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried and it returned nothing. How do I know if it works?

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit odd to answer my own question but I did finally fix it somehow like a blind fly. I hope to write down the experience maybe who else is totally like me as a absolute beginner with everything wouldn't get struggling overnight.

Stage 1: from gem to homebrew (failed)

At the beginning, I did remove items that install in gem item-by-item, then I install brew-gem to do it. At some stage, it work for jekyll but not my theme. It kept popping out I didn't install a package that the theme needs even I installed it manually. So in the end, I remove everything related to jekyll from homebrew.

Stage 2: back to gem (very long path but finally made it)

I later found a [page](https://gist.github.com/r-brown/a0b50d56cfb3596e0d17) tell step-by-step to install jekyll. I am using OSX 10.13 (High Sierra) that cause me the permission problem. So I just granted access with this line:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/*
```

The * is a must or it won't work. I did the same to the ruby part

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/*
```

After that I install jekyll and bundler carefully following the instruction. And install the packages that the theme needs manually through `gem install`, which you can find at the Gemfile. I got the problem of jekyll-sitemap similar as [this](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4972), I followed the method to install pygment.rb through `gem install pygments.rb`. And now my site is locally work.

Comment: I personally do not recommend to install under homebrew (even tho it's seducing to manage everything under one thing) because I was failed to make it work and I found some posts they also not to recommend and better go through the original way.