# Somehow broke my terminal when exporting a PATH

Tags: shell, path, zsh

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66343887/17337979) on Stackoverflow.
After I executed the command, no other commands work from any plugin. Can't even run `git status` on a local repo. I just get the error `zsh: command not found:`

Iterm doesnt even display the branch name next to the file path, so something is seriously up... Any ideas?

This was the command in my case:
`export PATH="/Users/tillman/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.1.0/bin:$PATH"`

Terminal within VS Code works fine, but iTerm does not.

Problem is I can't actually see the above path added to my .zshrc file. So I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Is that literally the error message you get? I can't repro with `zsh`. What's the output of `echo "$PATH"`?

Comment: After the words _command not found_, zsh should print **which** command was not found. BTW, did you check your PATH manually, to see whether it is correct?

Comment: yup, I did check my PATH with echo $PATH. I should've been more clear that zsh was stating ```command not found``` for **all** commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39812398/17337979).

I still don't totally know why this works, so if anyone has the time to answer it would be great.
The commands were not working because of every one of these paths. Each one broke my shell:

- `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:$PATH"`
- `export PATH="$HOME/.gem/ruby/3.1.0/bin:$PATH"`
- `export PATH="$HOME/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.1.0/bin"`

But these commands came from the [Jekyll install guide](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/macos/). After running these commands once, my terminal still worked for days (terminal was restarted multiple times between different sessions after running those commands). It was only after running the `export` command from the OP where everything broke. From there, I had to delete the above three `export` commands before the shell would work again...

Really confusing. Particularly as the `export` command never actually ended up in my .zshrc file after running it at all....

Comment: The ones which don't include the previous value of `$PATH` are broken because it removes access to essential utilities. If you know what you are doing, you can still reach e.g. `/bin/ls` instead of just `ls` but of course, you don't want to be forced to do that. The first one should work, as such, but probably you had already wrecked the previous value of `PATH` by other means at that point.

Comment: Tangentially, you only need to `export` a variable once; the shell remembers this setting even if you later change the value of the variable (and the `PATH` should already be marked by export by your shell anyway).

Comment: Ok great. Thanks for the extra answers!